# Find And Replace Folder Names On Server

Tags: php, linux, ftp, replace

I can't seem to find a way to do this on my dedicated server.

I've got a huge directory of folders and some of then contain 3 dashes like '---' which I need to find and replace with just one dash.

Is there an easy way to do a find and replace right on my server? I really don't want to have to download all the folders and do it on my desktop and re-upload them.

Comment: You want to do this with PHP? Use `glob`, `str_replace` and `rename`

Comment: Or if you feel OOP, `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
find  ./  -name '*'  -exec  rename  's/---/-/g'  {}  \;
```

* **HAS NOT BEEN TESTED**

[src](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/760/find-recursively-from-current-directory-down-files-and-directories-whose-names-contain-single-or-multiple-whitespaces-and-replace-each-such-occurrence-with-a-single-underscore.)